# Unable to find a suitable output format for 'libvorbis' libvorbis: Invalid argument

Tags: 16.10, ffmpeg, ogg-vorbis, webm

I’m trying to convert some files to webm with ffmpeg using the following command:

```
# First pass
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec:v libvpx -quality best -b:v 225k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate 300k -bufsize 1000k -threads 8 -vf -an -pass 1 -f webm /dev/null

# Second pass
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec:v libvpx -quality best -b:v 225k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate 300k -bufsize 1000k -threads 8 -vf -codec:a libvorbis -b:a 128k -pass 2 -f webm output.webm
```

But I’m getting this error message:

```
[NULL @ 0x55c5d4360220] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'libvorbis'
libvorbis: Invalid argument
```

I have already installed libvorbis0a, libvorbisenc2 and libvorbisfile3 so I  searched in the repository but  can’t find any libvorbis package (only a libvorbis-dev what I guess is for compile it?)

So really I need to compile it or I’m doing something wrong? (I'm on Ubuntu 16.10)

Comment: If you need additional `ffmpeg` help please provide the complete console output from each command. In this case the first command would have failed with something like: `No such filter: '-an'. Error opening filters!` which would have been a more obvious error (due to the order of the options following the bogus `-vf` option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what was effective for me:

Pass1:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -an -c:v libvpx -quality best -b:v 225k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate 300k -bufsize 1000k -threads 4 -pass 1 -f webm /dev/null
```

Pass2:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx -quality best -b:v 225k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate 300k -bufsize 1000k -threads 4 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 128k -pass 2 -f webm output.webm
```

Note: I changed threads to 4 as I don't have 8. Changing that back to suit your system should not be a problem. I also changed the long hand '-codec: ' to the shorter `-c:` variant (force of habit) and moved the -an (no audio switch) to the front of pass 1 (I'm not sure that it's required in this instance but it's not hurting anything). and of course I stripped out the spurious -vf (video filter) switch as mentioned by @LordNeckbeard that was causing the error you were receiving on the 2nd pass as well as the unseen error piped to /dev/null ""Trailing options were found on the commandline. " on the first pass.

Comment: It works like a charm so it was a problem with the ffmpeg command itself. Anyway to not worry for the num of threads we can use $(nproc) variable instead of a number too.

Thank you both for your help ;)

Comment: @Akarin Always glad to help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have the `-vf` (video filter) option in each command, but you didn't provide any filter names for it. Either add a filter or remove the errant `-vf` from each command.

Comment: I think that's part of it. I get "Trailing options were found on the commandline.
" when I eliminate the route to /dev/null in the first line. The error is unchanged upon removal of -vf  I don't do a lot of 2 pass encodes. Does stripping the audio with -an on the first pass make sense to you in this case? Since it's only creating the log file during the first pass for video encoding isn't that -an superfluous?

Comment: @ElderGeek For the very rare cases that I have done 2-pass I always used `-an` on the first pass. With libx264 some users have reported some sort of error when including `-an`, and there is a bug report about it I think, but I don't ever recall encountering whatever issue it was. Can't remember the details regarding the alleged error, but audio doesn't get any benefits from two passes.

Comment: Agreed. I was under the impression that there was no audio data included in the 1st pass log file since it's not utilized in that step although it appears that without the -an switch ffmpeg reports processing it even during a first pass. I didn't take the time to fully test to see if forcing the dropping of audio data during the first pass saves any time by ignoring that stream and was wondering if you had any insights. Perhaps I'll test that..

Comment: If your interested I posted the results [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/881704/does-the-an-switch-speed-up-the-first-pass-of-a-2-pass-ffmpeg-encode/881705#881705)