# Does the -an switch speed up the first pass of a 2 pass ffmpeg encode?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

I've seen a number of 2-pass encode examples and they often use the -an switch on the first pass. This seems to be because on the first pass only video data is sampled for the log file used by the second pass to create a more efficient encoding. I noticed this switch again when answering [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881389/unable-to-find-a-suitable-output-format-for-libvorbis-libvorbis-invalid-argum/881502#881502) and I'm wondering if there is any effect whatsoever in using this switch on the first pass of a 2 pass encode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Any effect at all?**

Yes. Using the -an switch causes ffmpeg to skip processing the audio stream.

**Any positive benefit?**

Yes there is a measurable decrease in processing time..
I took a 60 second mp4 source clip to use for testing and issued the command

`time ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -y -an -c:v libvpx -quality best -b:v 225k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate 300k -bufsize 1000k -threads 4 -pass 1 -f webm /dev/null`

I obtained the following output:

```
frame= 1799 fps=174 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Output file is empty, nothing was encoded

```
real    0m10.477s
user    0m12.972s
sys 0m0.188s
```

and then renamed the resulting log file an.log for comparison later.

I ran the command again without the -an switch as in

`time ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -y -c:v libvpx -quality best -b:v 225k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate 300k -bufsize 1000k -threads 4 -pass 1 -f webm /dev/null`

The resulting output was:

```
frame= 1799 fps=165 q=0.0 Lsize=     505kB time=00:01:00.01 bitrate=  68.9kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:483kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 4.367473%

    real    0m11.088s
    user    0m13.792s
    sys 0m0.156s
```

So it looks like it's a little bit faster to run the first pass with the -an

**Any change to the 1st pass log file?**
No. As expected the log files are identical as running `diff` on them proves.

Comment: Passing `-an` after the input file means only that no audio is encoded. I'm not sure fit his will also prevent audio from getting decoded from the source file; this may be the case as a side effect of no established mapping but I'm not a FFMPEG expert. To be absolutely sure, place `-an` prior to the input file as then no audio is decoded from that file and thus also for sure never encoded.

Comment: @Mecki Nice catch. Is it any faster with the approach you suggested?